# Project using PCL 'TPL Dataflow' won't compile when targetting .NET 4.5.2

Tags: task-parallel-library, portable-class-library, tpl-dataflow, .net-4.5.2

I'm using Windows 7 Pro x64 SP1 and Visual Studio 2012 Update 4.  I can't get my VB.NET WPF project to compile when using the TPL Dataflow package and .NET 4.5.2.  I've created a base project with nothing except this code and compile only for x64:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow

Class MainWindow
    Dim test As New System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.BufferBlock(Of String)
End Class
```

I've tried adding the facade reference to System.Runtime.dll and System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll with no effect.  It compiles fine if I change to .NET 4.5.  I must have a reference to 4.5.2 because of other features that will be in the project that require it.

Specific errors:

> Warning   1   The primary reference "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". TPLDataflow4.5.2Demo
>
> Warning   2   The primary reference "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". TPLDataflow4.5.2Demo
>
> Warning   3   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. F:\Projects\TPLDataflow4.5.2Demo\TPLDataflow4.5.2Demo\MainWindow.xaml.vb    1   9   TPLDataflow4.5.2Demo
>
> Error 4   Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.BufferBlock' is not defined.  F:\Projects\TPLDataflow4.5.2Demo\TPLDataflow4.5.2Demo\MainWindow.xaml.vb    4   21  TPLDataflow4.5.2Demo

**Solution:**

It turns out the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack I was using had a bug that wouldn't let PCLs compile correctly.

I downloaded and installed the updated version of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2901951 and my application was able to compile without errors.

Comment: How are you targeting those versions of Runtime and Tracing? The correct strong name for those, for both .NET 4.0 and 4.5, has a version of "4.0.0.0"

Comment: TPL Dataflow is a closed Microsoft package from NuGet and they reference in there.  I realize that 4.5.2 is an in-place upgrade, but i'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Also, the versions really come from microsoft and can be found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\RedistList\FrameworkList.xml".  The versions are correct, but for some reason the redirect is failing wheh using .NET 4.5.2 instead of 4.5

Comment: There seems to be an open ticket in [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/873446/project-targeting-4-5-2-fails-to-build-when-referencing-a-pcl) regarding targeting PCL libraries with .NET 4.5.2

Comment: That really looks like what is going on.  I found that all the redirects exist as part of the .NET multi-targeting packs.  Works fine with 4.5.1 and 4.5, just not 4.5.2.  Yikes.  I'll try downloading the update and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Ahh I see. "TPL Dataflow won't compile" is very misleading.

Comment: Changed the title, is it better?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov:  I installed the updated 4.5.2 dev pack and it fixed it.  Please change your comment to a solution so I can accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ticket on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/873446/project-targeting-4-5-2-fails-to-build-when-referencing-a-pcl) specifying the use of .NET 4.5.2 with PCL libraries causing builds to fail.

This was fixed in the [*Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2901951)

> When you recompile a Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 application that uses .NET portable libraries to target the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2, you receive the following error message during compilation:
>
> The type '{type}' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly '{assembly}'